# jenkins.war stop error “Name or service not known”

Tags: linux, jenkins, dns

I have a jenkins service running in linux(no docker), sometimes service dont response
when I excute "service --status-all" command show .war is stop
in jenkins log show this message

```
WARNING: Could not intialize the host network interface on nullbecause of an error: myserver: myserver: Name or service not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: myserver: myserver: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
        at javax.jmdns.impl.HostInfo.newHostInfo(HostInfo.java:75)
        at javax.jmdns.impl.JmDNSImpl.<init>(JmDNSImpl.java:407)
        at javax.jmdns.JmDNS.create(JmDNS.java:60)
        at hudson.DNSMultiCast$1.call(DNSMultiCast.java:33)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: myserver: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
```

if I restart service run normally but this problem is very inconvenient

Comment: it says that a host name called `myserver` cannot be resolved. Not sure, when and why this is looked up, but better place the real host name there where you specified this string.

Comment: where i can change this hostname? you know?

Answer (score 1):

Adding your `hostname` to `/etc/hosts` might help.